# Dispatcher doesn't update ListBox control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Here's the ListBox itself:

```xml
...
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxTemplate" DataType="ArticlesApp:Article">
            <StackPanel Margin="6, 10, 0, 0" Height="45">
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author, StringFormat='by {0}'}"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
...
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ListBox" SelectionChanged="ListBox_OnSelectionChanged" Background="#444444" SelectionMode="Single" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxTemplate}"/>
```

And Dispatcher in code behind:

```cs
        public ArticlesView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ...

            Dispatcher?.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { ListBox.ItemsSource = GetArticles(); }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
        }

        public static List<Article> GetArticles()
        {
            var articles = new List<Article>();

            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("articles", "*.json", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                File.OpenText(file);

                articles.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Article>(File.ReadAllText(file)));
            }

            return articles;
        }
```

It works on the application launch, assigning `ListBox` ItemSource to `GetArticles`, but after it doesn't do anything, if something changes.

Comment: @Clemens I mean, if the binding changes, the changes should apply also on ListBox. For example, if a folder, which is listened in ListBox as an item, is deleted, then it should also disappear in ListBox, and vise versa.

Comment: @Clemens There's a dummy binding in the above code for example, because the problem isn't in it, I sure. If I manually update the ListBox, by clicking on a button with `UpdateListBox` method, it works well.

Comment: @Clemens As I said, that was just a dummy. Now I posted the real code.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, I know, just forget about Binding, now I posted the real code instead of that example.

Comment: @Clemens I did this before and it worked, I don't really understand, why this isn't working in Dispatcher right now. It just searches JSON files in a specific directory, deserialize them, get some data from and then put in ListBox as the ItemSource. I also have defined DataTemplate with bindings from `Article` class for ListBox in XAML. See the updated post to understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: I can't see any binding on the `ItemsSource` and `ListBox.ItemsSource = GetArticles();` is only called in the constructor. Why do you expect the content of the `ListBox` to change after the constructor call? This is not possible. Not the way you implemented it.

Comment: Could it be that you just wanted to call that method cyclically and you are confusing Dispatcher and DispatcherTimer?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of Using List , use ObservableCollection so that whenever source will change it will auto trigger the INotifyPropertyChange and INotifyCollectionChange and itemsource will retake from the collection.

```
public static ObservableCollection<Article> GetArticles()
    {

        var articles = new ObservableCollection<Article>();

        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("articles", "*.json", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            File.OpenText(file);
            articles.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Article>(File.ReadAllText(file)));
        }

        return articles;
    }
```

Comment: This wouldn't help much, because you would create a new ObservableCollection each time the method is called, and presumably not change it in the meantime. Then it doesn't matter of it's an ObservableCollection or a plain List.

Comment: I Think it will work as @flakerz mention that it is working on the launch of application. As he used dispatcher periority as     
                                                                              
            Dispatcher?.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { ListBox.ItemsSource = GetArticles(); }), DispatcherPriority.Background);                                                      As Dispatcher Priority is BAckground  so it will run after all the background run is finished. So item source should be notify that any changed happened in the collection

Comment: Of course the ItemsSource will be set, but it doesn't matter if it's set to a List or an ObservableCollection. There won't be a difference, since no items are later added to or removed from the collection.